# Laravel current route name contains

Tags: laravel

I have a group of routes like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
    Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
    Route::put('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.update', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@update']);
    Route::get('{id}/read', ['as' => 'messages.read', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@read']); // ajax + Pusher
});
```

In my side bar I'd like to highlight the area the user is in when they click on any of these routes:

```
<li class="d-flex flex-column {{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'messages') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

This would work if the route was 'messages'. is there away I can do it to be like Route::currentRouteNameContains... Obviously that's not a Laravel method but how can I have it active if it CONTAINS messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [str_contains](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-str-contains) helper function

```html
<li class="d-flex flex-column {{ str_contains(Route::currentRouteName(), 'messages') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Beware that this would return true even if the route is `/user/chat/messages/unread` which is probably not what you want

You may look at [starts_with](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-starts-with)

```html
<li class="d-flex flex-column {{ starts_with(Route::currentRouteName(), 'messages') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

#### Laravel 6+ users

The helper functions no longer ship with the default installation

You need to install the [laravel/helpers](https://github.com/laravel/helpers) package

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Comment: money @Caddy DZ

Comment: The first one worked for me but I gotta wait 10 minutes before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getPrefix()** helper function, too.

```
{{ request()->route()->getPrefix() === '/messages' ? 'active' : '' }}
```

Also you can use **Route** facades to do this. result will same with first

```
{{ Route::current()->getPrefix() === '/messages' ? 'active' : '' }}
```

Or combine **basename()** like below

```
{{ basename(request()->route()->getPrefix()) === 'messages' ? 'active' : '' }}
```